# Removing old text labels when bar chart is updated

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I am trying to build a D3 bar chart visualization that can be updated using a drop down menu.

So far, I have successfully created the bar chart and the drop down menu such that when I change the selection in the menu, the bars are updated to their new values.

However, I am having problems with the bar labels updating appropriately. Even though I include the same `.exit.remove()` function for the labels as for the bars, the old labels remain on the newly updated chart.

[Image of the updated chart w/ problem labels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qTymc.png)

[Test csv file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/o5bf1simy7vpuo8/test_veg.csv?dl=0)

[Test code](https://www.dropbox.com/s/jjjcgd8cirb46cu/test_veg.html?dl=0)

Apologies for the links. I'm new to JSFiddle, and I couldn't figure out how to easily transfer my example.

Comment: Please include the relevant data, rather than links to external sites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You forgot to add class attribute while appending the text
2. You also need to change the text while updating

   Hope this helps

   `bartexts.transition().duration(250)
        .attr("y", function(d, i) {return yScale(d) - 10})
        .text(function(d) {return d});`